# Select the previous X rows

Tags: mysql

Pretty simple:  I want to select previous 10 rows from a table called Image starting at X.  Normally, it would just look something like:

```
"select * from image order by image_id desc limit X, 10"
```

However, I want the previous 10 rows after X, not the next 10 rows (so, I want x-1, x-2, x-3, etc. instead of x+1, x+2, x+3, etc.).

Any easy way of doing this?

By the way, Image has 3 columns: image_id (primary, AI), image_link, and timestamp.

EDIT: The reason why I can't do "order by image_id asc" is because I want to build a list that goes from newest to oldest.  Ordering by ascending would create the list as oldest to newest.

Comment: change `image_id desc` to `asc` ?

Comment: Good point but the purpose of this is to display a large list of items starting at the most recent and then, as you go, going down to oldest.

Since doing order by asc would start me at row 1, the I would then be going from oldest to newest.  Same thing if I did "order by timestamp desc", I would still have the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think its pretty simple

```
select * from image order by image_id desc limit (X-10), 10
```

Comment: Totally just realized how much of a brain fart I had.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT image_id, name
FROM
(
    SELECT 
      *, @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank
    FROM image, (SELECT @rownum := 0) t 
    ORDER BY image_id DESC
) t
WHERE rank BETWEEN  10-5 AND 10;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cc974/5)